# jQuery can't find element when it's parsed from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

At first I made a simple array just inside the .js file and wrote the function to make list items from it.
Then clicking on freshly created li elements should do something.

```
//This code works

dic[0] = "decir";
dic[1] = "querer";
dic[2] = "poder";


$(document).ready(
    function verbsarray() {

        for (var i = 0; i < dic.length; i++) {      
                var verbo = dic[i];                         
                verbos += "<li class='h_li'>" + verbo + "</li>\n";
        };          
        $('ul.h_list').html(verbos);                       
});    

$(".h_li").click(function() {
    alert("it works!");
    //Dollar finds .h_li here
}
```

Since that was a prototype, then I developed that function to take items not from the static array, but from loaded JSON.
Function parses the needed items and again makes list items from them.

But the other function (that looks for clicked `<li class="h_li">`) now doesn't work...

```
//this doesnt work :-( 

function verbos_from_json () {

    $.getJSON('verbos.json', function verbsarray(vjson) {
        for (var i = 0; i < vjson.data.length; i++) {       
            verbo = vjson.data[i].verb;                         
            verbos += "<li class='h_li'>" + verbo + "</li>\n";
        };      

        $('ul.h_list').html(verbos);
        });         
};

$(".h_li").click(function() {
    alert("it works?.. no");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically rendered elements, you need to use delegate binding with `jquery`. Instead of `click()`:

```
$(".h_li").click(function() {
    alert("it works?.. no");
};
```

use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(".h_list").on('click', '.h_li', function() {
    alert("it works?.. no");
};
```

Comment: The idea is correct but you didn't use `.on()` correctly for delegation. You need to provide a selector as the second argument. `$('.h_list').on('click', '.h_li', function () { ... });`. In addition, when delegating, attach the event listener to the parent (i.e. `.h_list`) not the the individual `.h_li` elements themselves.

Comment: @War10ck - that's correct - clerical error. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll update the answer

Comment: Your edit is almost there. Update the first selector to be the parent `.h_list` and not the individual element `.h_li`...

Comment: Thanks! This solution works!

Answer (score 1):

You have to integrate your listening function in your verbos_from_json

```
function verbos_from_json () {

$.getJSON('verbos.json', function verbsarray(vjson) {
    for (var i = 0; i < vjson.data.length; i++) {       
        verbo = vjson.data[i].verb;                         
        verbos += "<li class='h_li'>" + verbo + "</li>\n";
    };      

    $('ul.h_list').html(verbos);
 //****************************************************************
    //}); // bad place : it was a typo ( edited after discussion ) 
 //****************************************************************

// THIS PART HAS MOVED IN
$(".h_li").click(function() {
// better to off before (if is safe for you) to prevent multiple event
// $(".h_li").off('click').click(function() {

    alert("it works?.. no");
}
}); // it was a typo ( edited after discussion ) 
};
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It doesnt matter whether the click event handler is within the function closure but I would think its better the way the OP has it now.

Comment: No it is very important ! $.getJson is asynchronous and you just ask to listen to a list of element and after you want it interact whith new ones without binding to the newer ones !

Comment: That is not correct either. Check out my answer (with the help of Warlock) and the duplicate comment on the OP

Comment: this is exactly what i have said !

Comment: For this to work like you've shown, the `$('.h_li').click(...);` part would need to be inside `$.getJSON()`'s success callback function.

Comment: you're right there were copy/paste error ! this my fault ! But the explanations was correct

Comment: Much better. This method will work, however notice my comment on _@madi_'s answer about the advantages of using event delegation. Either way, this is now a valid solution as well...

Comment: I agree totaly with delegation !

Answer (score 1):

Since the elements are added after ajax call. The click event is not attached to new elements that are added asynchronously . I will do this:

```
function verbos_from_json () {

    $.getJSON('verbos.json', function verbsarray(vjson) {
        for (var i = 0; i < vjson.data.length; i++) {       
            verbo = vjson.data[i].verb;                         
            verbos += "<li class='h_li'>" + verbo + "</li>\n";
        };      

        $('ul.h_list').html(verbos);

        // bind here
        $( ".h_li" ).bind( "click", function() {
                alert( "It works" );
        });
    });         
};
```

**{OR}**

As mentioned by War10ck delegation can be done instead of binding in the json.

Change:

```
$(".h_li").click(function() {
    alert("it works?.. no");
};
```

To:

```
$( ".h_list" ).delegate( ".h_li", "click", function() { 
      alert("It works?.....no") 
})
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, though you'll have `n` number of event listeners where `n = vjson.data.length` as oppose to just one event listener if delegated using `.on()`. It's more memory intensive though probably not enough to make a noticable difference within the UI.

Comment: In that case , mike can use $( ".h_list" ).delegate( ".h_li", "click", function() {
  alert("It works?.....no")
});

Comment: Thanks, but moving the click listener just under the json's load was my the first action. But that wouldn't help.